# Highlighting sometimes fails when previewing a post

Tags: bug, markdown-preview, highlighting

When I highlight a line of text on a post I am composing, sometimes the text un-highlights itself, and focus returns to the textbox.

## Steps to reproduce:

1. Navigate to the "Ask a Question" page, for example by using the "Ask Question" link.
2. Enter text into the text box. Text will appear in the preview window.
3. Highlight part of one line of the text in the preview window.

When you release the mouse button after highlighting, the text will no longer be highlighted, and the cursor in the text box will resume blinking.

## Recordings of bug:

> [image]

This happens even if the line wraps, like so:

> [image]

But the text *does* remain highlighted as expected if I highlight multiple lines, like so:

> [image]

## Additional information:

This happens on every page I have tried that has a preview window – asking a question, answering a question, or editing a post.

This happens on every Stack Exchange site that I have tried – Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Exchange, and Board & Card Games.

[Another user](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16177419#16177419) has also experienced this problem.

**Technical specs**
Me: Windows 7, Firefox 17.0.8
Fenikso: Windows 7, Firefox 28

Comment: Yep, I've noticed this behavior as well. I haven't thought to mention it because it's not too hard to just highlight the non-markdown text instead...and I can still copy text from the markdown preview by hitting Ctrl+C before letting go of the left click (i.e., while it's still highlighted)...but I could imagine situations where this would be more frustrating than those I've encountered so far.